# Jquery submit event not firing

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to submit a form using jquery. I am running a Django server.

The JS Code and HTML are as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    // Submit comment form
    document.querySelector('#comment-form').addEventListener("submit", function(event){event.preventDefault()});
    document.querySelector('#comment-form').addEventListener('submit', () => save_comment());

});

function save_comment() {
    console.log('Save function triggered');
    frm = document.querySelector('#comment-form');

    data_submit = {
        updated_comment: frm.querySelector('#comment-editbox').value,
        month: frm.querySelector('#comment-mth').value,
        gl_code: frm.querySelector('#comment-gl').value,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
    };
    console.log('Save function triggered 2');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        console.log('Submit triggered');
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: data_submit,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("successful");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("failed");
            }
        });
        console.log('save ended');
        return false;
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <label id="comment-heading">Comments  <span id="comment-subheading"></span></label>
        <form action="{% url 'comment' %}" method="post" id='comment-form'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea id="comment-editbox" name="comment-editbox"></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" id="comment-mth" name="comment-mth" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="comment-gl" name="comment-gl" value="">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" id='comment-save'>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

"Save function triggered" and "Save function triggered 2" get logged onto the console when I submit the form. But "Submit triggered" does not.

The form does get submitted to the server which returns a json response and causes the form to navigate to the response route. I do not want the form to redirect to the response route or reload the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PS. The snippet won't work as it is not complete. Cannot run backend code here.

Comment: Where is the jQuery submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using?

```
frm.submit(function (e) {
   ...
});
```

You are calling submit method on the DOM and passing in a function to it. There is no function with submit(); Those two lines should be removed.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#comment-form').addEventListener('submit', save_comment);
});

function save_comment(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Save function triggered');
  const frm = document.querySelector('#comment-form');

  const data_submit = {
    updated_comment: frm.querySelector('#comment-editbox').value,
    month: frm.querySelector('#comment-mth').value,
    gl_code: frm.querySelector('#comment-gl').value,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(),
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: data_submit,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("successful");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("failed");
    }
  });
  console.log('save ended');
}
```

Comment: That was noobish of me. Thanks!